# How do functional language gui bindings work?

Tags: user-interface, functional-programming, mutable

Do they typically use non functional aspects of the language (including mutable variables).
Are there other strategies? Could you describe them?

Answer (score 4):

> Do they typically use non functional aspects of the language (including mutable variables)

Many do, yes. In case of haskell, which doesn't have mutable variables or functions with side-effects, they use the IO monad (which is haskell's way of encapsulating side-effects)-

> Are there other strategies? Could you describe them?

Yes, there are. Look at [functional reactive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming).